# Using sentry logging with elasticsearch

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, log4j, sentry

I try to store all the logs at sentry instance. Accordingly to [this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sentry-support/11992/3) I tried the following:

Added sentry appender to loggin.yml:

```
es.logger.level: INFO
rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console, sentry
...
appender:
  console:
    type: console
    layout:
      type: consolePattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  sentry: 
    type: net.kencochrane.raven.log4j.SentryAppender 
    dsn: "http://...@..."
```

And copied `raven-5.0.jar`, `raven-log4j-5.0.jar` and `raven-logback-5.0.jar` to es/lib folder. No errors during start but sentry has no records even with warning messages at console. ES's version is 2.1.0.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the valid solution (for ES 2.4.4):

1. Add following libraries to `lib` folder of ES: `raven-7.8.2.jar`, `raven-log4j-7.8.2.jar`, `slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar`, `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.24.jar`
2. Update `config/logging.yml`:

   ```
   rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console, file, sentry

   /* other appenders */

   sentry:
      type: com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender 
      dsn: <DSN_HERE> 
      threshold: INFO
   ```
3. Restart ES instance