# How to set elasticsearch to push data to sentry

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j2, sentry

I have elasticsearch 5.6 and using log4j2 to config it now,
I save data in elasticsearch, And now i want to push data to sentry 8.22.
If elasticsearch reviceve a data then push the data to sentry automatically.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

PS:
I found some links like this [Using sentry logging with elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894776/using-sentry-logging-with-elasticsearch)
But the solution there is too old.

Answer (score 0):

IMO that's not what Sentry is for: You want to find errors in **your** application, but it isn't a general log collector. You're also not trying to get your operating system, webserver, database,... hooked into Sentry, right?

If anything in Elasticsearch is going wrong, Sentry should collect the error in your application and you can dig deeper from there. No need to connect Elasticsearch directly.

PS: Adding logging libraries is definitely untested and you might run into various issues (at the very least every upgrade will be more complicated) — I'd be pretty careful with this.